# How to add sources directory to the scope of require() in npm?

Tags: javascript, npm

I have this directory structure:

```
package.json
/src
  a.js
/test
  test_a.js
```

This is the content of `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "6.1.4"
  }
}
```

This is what I'm doing in `test_a.js`:

```
var a = require('a');
```

And I'm getting:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'a'
```

However, when I change it to this, everything works fine:

```
var a = require('../src/a');
```

The questions is: how do I configure `package.json` so that it knows where my modules are and I would not need to specify them by the "absolute" path `../src/`?

Comment: based on reading [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15755) - no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot resolve dynamic modules with `require("a")` because there can be a file called `a.js` in your project folder and there can an npm package in `node_modules/a`, and can lead to more errors.

But there are options you can do to avoid the usage of `require("../src/")`.

One such option explained below (using babel)

Folder structure

```
src/
  level1/
    b.js
  a.js
test/
  a.test.js
```

**Step 1**

Install babel and a few other dependencies

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

**Step 2**

Create and Configure `.babelrc` file in project root.

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "module-resolver",
            {
                "root": [
                    "./src"
                ],
                "alias": {
                    "level1": "./src/level1"
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Here in `module-resolver` section I have added 2 aliases for folder paths.

`"root": ["./src"]` enables access to any file in `src` folder using `require("/path_to_file")`. Ex:- `require("/a")`, `require("/level1/b")`

`"alias": {"level1": "./src/level1"}` enables access to any file in `src/level1` folder using `require("level1/path_to_file")`. Ex:- `require("level1/b")`

**Step 3**

Run your tests using `mocha --require @babel/register`.

Final `package.json` would look like below.

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require @babel/register",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.6.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
    "mocha": "6.1.4"
  }
}
```

**a.test.js**

```
var a = require("/a");
var level1 = require("level1/b");

var assert = require("assert");
describe("a.js", function() {
    it("should return `Hello from A`", function() {
      assert.equal(a(), "Hello from A");
    });
});

describe("b.js", function() {
  it("should return `Hello from B`", function() {
    assert.equal(level1(), "Hello from B");
  });
});
```

Relevant docs

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/

https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver